# Roblox Suddenly Lagging

Tags: roblox

So I know there are similar questions on Google, but they had something to do with their Nvidia driver, which I don't have or any way to get it (I'm just a kid, I don't have enough knowledge to go through my PC stats and get an Nvidia driver or whatnot).

I did try the reducing lag methods (such as going into Roblox studio and turning off frame manager and changing the render distance to a lower resolution), but I still get stuttering frames, just barely-noticeable but gameplay-changing amounts of lag and just overall server lagging (pressing a key and the function of the key happening about a second later, people teleporting and such).

This isn't my PC problem - my 2 PCs had no problem running Roblox about 2 days ago, then one day I turned on my wireless PC and it just seems to have lag. I thought this may be just it being wireless and tried my wired one, but that had the exact same problem. I also tried disabling my antivirus on my big PC, which did seem to get rid of a tiny bit of lag but still lagging the same way nonetheless. Others seem to not have this problem, re-installing or restarting the PC doesn't work, and Roblox didn't update until today (which still lags). This is extremely frustrating, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to visit other simple games, such as Escape Prison Obby? Whenever I play complex games like Jailbreak I often lag.

Comment: Well I only tried Void Script Builder and Reason 2 Die, and even in completely empty VIP servers in VSB it still had the same lag.

Comment: And that still doesnt explain why I suddnly started lagging in games that ran perfectly fine before on both pc's.

Comment: I tried the game, it doesnt have people teleporting, but my chat still takes about 1 second to get sent.

Comment: Also, I can no longer hold the backspace button to delete all my messages like in here, if that mattered(I have to spam-tap backspace to delete my chat, unlike just holding them)

Comment: AND NOW CLICK FUNCTIONS DO NOT WORK PROPERLY. SOMEONE HELP!

Comment: maybe your internet connection is not good?

Comment: Another suggestion: play roblox on an ipad (with keyboard if you do not get used to joysticks), it does not lag that much.

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about the Nvidia driver. Do u mean you just need to update it? If so, its extremely easy to update a graphics card driver. Assuming you are running windows, just go to Device Manager, open display adapters, and select your graphics card. Then, click the upgrade driver software button on the top of the window. (The one with the green arrow pointing upwards). That's it.